# R tm stopwords not removing accented words

Tags: r, tm, stop-words

I'm applying `tm_map` function to a spanish corpus for removing spanish stopwords and some other specific words like this:

```
exampleCorpus <- tm_map(exampleCorpus, removeWords, c('puede', 'qué','que', stopwords('spanish')))
```

Is working fine with all words except with **qué**.

Is there something I'm missing about dealing with accented characters?

Comment: `library(tm);corp <- Corpus(VectorSource("puede qué que test"));corp <- tm_map(corp, removeWords, c('puede', 'qué','que', stopwords('spanish')));content(corp[[1]])` works fine. Maybe an encoding issue?

Comment: I'm loading my corpues from a column of a previous loaded csv, I'm looking into it